#  How do I add my network drive to Wine to use applications from there?

Tags: networking, windows, wine

I am a new Wine user. I have a Windows PC that is sharing files to my Linux machine. I can see the stuff that I shared from my network directory but in Wine I want to be able to use those exe's that are on the share with Wine.

There's no option in Wine to map network drives but I'm not entirely too clear on how to go about using that.

So, how do I add my network drive to Wine to use applications from there?

Answer (score 3):

Just mount them through your Ubuntu desktop, either by clicking their bookmarks or setting up a new connection using "Connect to server".

Then, you can map a drive in Wine's configuration settings dialog to `/home/username/.gvfs`, a (normally hidden) folder in which virtual folders represent your network shares.

Obviously, `username` must be substituted with your own username (run `whoami` to find out).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how do I mount them to my desktop with bookmarks and when is the connect to server option? Thanks.

Comment: So you haven't mounted your drives yet? Either on the desktop or in the file manager, go to File -> Connect to server...

Comment: Yes I think I have them mounted because I can see in my network benedette-pc which is the name of the pc that is sharing the files to me and I can access it. Also I think ive successfully mounted my drive to that .gvfs place you were talking about because I can access files from there

Comment: In 14.04 LTS, these are now located in /run/user/9999/gvfs - substitute 9999 for your user id, type `id -u` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Apps installed to a different installation of Windows will most likely not work as they will be missing any library files installed to the windows system directories,and won't have any of their registry setup available.

Most times, you have to install the applications into wine itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is option to map network drive in Wine setup, but on Wine HQ they told: It is not yet implemented. (http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=5854&view=next)

Therefore you should:

- mount network drive to a local folder first.
- map drive letter in Wine setup to this (already local) folder.